# Arabic font gets cut in Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

It's look like wired behaviour of Android 4.0.

In my project there is some Arabic text.
While I am running that project in the emulator with Android 4.0 or any version then it looks fine. But when I run it on a real Android 4.0 device then it looks like the text is getting cut from the right side.
See the below Screen.

Screen 1: In Emulator

[image]

Screen 2: In Real Android 4.0 device

[image]

I can't understand why it is happen like this. How can I fix this?

code or row item:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="right">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/toptext" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Title"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" android:gravity="right" android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text=" "
            android:paddingRight="15dp" android:gravity="right" android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can u please tell me the font u have used??
Font name ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a working around: Try adding [right padding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3apaddingRight) to your views.

I had a similar issue with TextViews in ICS. they were cut from the bottom. Fortunately, Google solved this in Jelly Bean version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i have given it as android:padding="5dp" and it not solved my issue. Is there any other technique ??

Comment: You added it to the ListView or to its items? And is the Ayah a text or an Image?

Comment: its a Text not Image. And i have added it to its items, not to listView. Should i have to add it to ListView ?

Comment: Try adding it to the ListView and see what comes although I think it won't work. It is really a strange behavior. Did you try to test your app in another device? And if you could post the xml code of listview_items we may could help more.

Comment: Another thing you may try: what if there is no Tashkeel in the first char of the Ayah? Will it be cut also? May be that what cause the cutting.

Comment: iturki: i have updated question with code. please check it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Relative layout and right margin should be solutions.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toptext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toptextleft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toptext"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How it is seen? I miss </LinearLayout> :(

Answer (score 0):

Setting the TextView's `android:gravity` attribute value to `"start"` rather than `"left"` or `"right"` fixed it for me.