# Arabic Font Break

Tags: android

I am working on an Arabic App. I am wondering that my S3 is showing Arabic text correctly. But when I see the text in Emulator it is breaking. Any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this type of problem.After I found that for Arabic font we have to use specific type face files like **.ttf**

You can find some .ttf files which support only for Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `TextView` to show the Arabic text, try setting the `TextView`'s `android:gravity` attribute value to `"start"` rather than `"left"` or `"right"`. This fixed it for me.

See this question for more possible solutions:
[Arabic font gets cut in Android 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698883/arabic-font-gets-cut-in-android-4-0)